# trying to add progress bar to the console

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea, console, progress-bar

I've tried using this repository https://github.com/ctongfei/progressbar
for adding progress bar for my ray-tracing.
When I run a test, I get a lot of exceptions.

I absolutely have no idea what they mean and how to even start fixing them.

My test code:

```
 ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar("Test", 1000);
 int i = 0;
 while (i < 1000) {
      Thread.sleep(100);
      pb.step();
      i++;
 }
```

Error message I get:

> Jul 15, 2019 9:14:57 PM org.jline.utils.Log logr WARNING: Unable to
>   retrieve infocmp for type dumb-color java.io.IOException: Cannot run
>   program "infocmp": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the
>   file specified    at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1128)    at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1071)    at
>   org.jline.utils.InfoCmp.getInfoCmp(InfoCmp.java:547)  at
>   org.jline.terminal.impl.AbstractTerminal.parseInfoCmp(AbstractTerminal.java:187)
>     at org.jline.terminal.impl.DumbTerminal.(DumbTerminal.java:88)
>     at
>   org.jline.terminal.TerminalBuilder.doBuild(TerminalBuilder.java:401)
>     at org.jline.terminal.TerminalBuilder.build(TerminalBuilder.java:259)
>     at
>   me.tongfei.progressbar.ProgressThread.(ProgressThread.java:56)
>     at me.tongfei.progressbar.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:91)   at
>   me.tongfei.progressbar.ProgressBar.(ProgressBar.java:35)    at
>   main.Main.main(Main.java:70) Caused by: java.io.IOException:
>   CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)     at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:420)  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:151)   at
>   java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1107)
>     ... 10 more
>
> Test  99% │█████████████████████████▉│  996/1000 (0:01:40 / 0:00:00)
>   null

Comment: Looks like something with dumb terminal colouring, see https://github.com/jline/jline3/issues/328. Do you use colouring for terminal?

Comment: @DmitriyPopov no.

Answer (score 4):

I've created pull request for jline (see https://github.com/jline/jline3/pull/427)

As workaround for jline versions < 3.12 you can use following code (using IOUtils from apache-commons):

```java
   static {
        InfoCmp.setDefaultInfoCmp("dumb-color", () -> {
            try {
                return new String(IOUtils.toByteArray(InfoCmp.class.getResourceAsStream("/org/jline/utils/dumb-colors.caps")));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        });
    }
```